# How to properly set default values?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Regarding [this documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-a-more-structured-dsl), what is a proper way to set default values?

E.g.: Using the exmaple from the documentation, how can I set a default value for `config.name`?

And how can I define **required** and **optional** values using `Map config` as only parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a map on a script class level containing default values and you can simply combine two maps - one containing defaults and one provided as a parameter for the `call(Map config)` function.

Regarding required values, you can add `assert config.fieldName : 'Error message'` in the beginning of the `call()` function to test if user passed required values with `config` map. Take a look at this example:

```groovy
import groovy.transform.Field

// Map with the default values
@Field
Map defaults = [
    id: 0,
    name: 'test'
]

def call(Map config) {
    // Here we test if required config.id was set
    assert config.id : 'config.id must be set!'

    // Here we combine two maps and we allow to override default values
    config = defaults + config

    node {
        echo config.name
    }
}
```

Now, if I define my Jenkinsfile as:

```groovy
buildPlugin name: 'lorem', id: 13
```

and I run it, I will get following console output:

```
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test-pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
lorem
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

If I forgot to specify `id` parameter, pipeline will fail in the beginning:

```
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.AssertionError: config.id must be set!. Expression: assert config.id : 'config.id must be set!'
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.assertFailed(InvokerHelper.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.assertFailed(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:650)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.AssertBlock$ContinuationImpl.fail(AssertBlock.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:331)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:82)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:243)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:231)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Finished: FAILURE
```

And if I won't specify `config.name` parameter, the default one will be taken.